# CAS cannot find authentication handler that supports UsernamePasswordCredential

Tags: cas

I have a custom handler like this:

```
Public class DatabaseAuthenticationHandler extends AbstractJdbcUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler {

  @Override
  protected AuthenticationHandlerExecutionResult authenticateUsernamePasswordInternal(
        UsernamePasswordCredential credential, String originalPassword) throws GeneralSecurityException,    PreventedException {

    final String username = credential.getUsername();
    logger.debug("***Username:"+username);
    logger.debug("***Password:"+credential.getPassword());
    return createHandlerResult(credential, new SimplePrincipal(), null);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(final Credential credential)  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

To me,  this should always log a user in no matter what.  But I see in the logs this:

```
ERROR [org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] 
- <Authentication has failed. Credentials may be incorrect or CAS cannot find authentication handler that supports
[UsernamePasswordCredential(username=sadf, source=MyJDBCAuthenticationManager)] of type [UsernamePasswordCredential].
 Examine the configuration to ensure a method of authentication is defined and analyze CAS logs at DEBUG level to trace the authentication event.
```

which makes no sense to me as I can see in the logs that cas is calling the authenticatUsernamePasswordInternal method.  Obviously this handler supports, well everything.

Why can't I log in?

Answer (score 1):

I think you best use `principalFactory.createPrincipal` to create the principal rather than returning an `new SimplePrincipal()`.

In your `AuthenticationEventExecutionPlanConfigurer` & `DatabaseAuthenticationHandler`, add the following:

#### AuthenticationEventExecutionPlanConfigurer.java

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("principalFactory")
    private PrincipalFactory principalFactory;

    @Bean
    public DatabaseAuthenticationHandler databaseAuthenticationHandler() {
         return new DatabaseAuthenticationHandler(principalFactory);
    }
```

---

#### DatabaseAuthenticationHandler

```
Public class DatabaseAuthenticationHandler extends AbstractJdbcUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler {
  private final PrincipalFactory principalFactory;
  public DatabaseAuthenticationHandler (PrincipalFactory principalFactory){
     this.principalFactory = principalFactory;
  }

  @Override
  protected AuthenticationHandlerExecutionResult authenticateUsernamePasswordInternal(
        UsernamePasswordCredential credential, String originalPassword) throws GeneralSecurityException,    PreventedException {

    final String username = credential.getUsername();
    logger.debug("***Username:"+username);
    logger.debug("***Password:"+credential.getPassword());
    /////// below here's the change /////////
    return createHandlerResult(credential, this.principalFactory.createPrincipal(username), null);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(final Credential credential)  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

See if the above works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this problem is that you pass a null parameter to `createHandlerResult` method,you can change it to `new ArrayList<>`. I also encountered this problem(`My CAS version is 5.3.9`).And I also tried the solution gaving by Ng Sek Long,but it didn't work.Then I tried to solve it by myself. I searched for the error message in CAS code and found it in `PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager` class.

```
            try {
                  PrincipalResolver resolver = this.getPrincipalResolverLinkedToHandlerIfAny(handler, transaction);
                  LOGGER.debug("Attempting authentication of [{}] using [{}]", credential.getId(), handler.getName());
                  this.authenticateAndResolvePrincipal(builder, credential, resolver, handler);
                  AuthenticationCredentialsThreadLocalBinder.bindInProgress(builder.build());
                  Pair<Boolean, Set<Throwable>> failures = this.evaluateAuthenticationPolicies(builder.build(), transaction);
                  proceedWithNextHandler = !(Boolean)failures.getKey();
                } catch (Exception var15) {
                  LOGGER.error("Authentication has failed. Credentials may be incorrect or CAS cannot find authentication handler that supports [{}] of type [{}]. Examine the configuration to ensure a method of authentication is defined and analyze CAS logs at DEBUG level to trace the authentication event.", credential, credential.getClass().getSimpleName());
                  this.handleAuthenticationException(var15, handler.getName(), builder);
                  proceedWithNextHandler = true;
                }
```

In the above code snippet, the `authenticateAndResolvePrincipal` method declaired two kinds of exception.Looked at this method, I found there is a line of code which may throws that two.

```
 AuthenticationHandlerExecutionResult result = handler.authenticate(credential);
```

The key code which lead to this problem is in `DefaultAuthenticationHandlerExecutionResult` class.

```
  public DefaultAuthenticationHandlerExecutionResult(final AuthenticationHandler source, final CredentialMetaData metaData, final Principal p, @NonNull final List<MessageDescriptor> warnings) {
    this(StringUtils.isBlank(source.getName()) ? source.getClass().getSimpleName() : source.getName(), metaData, p, warnings);
    if (warnings == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("warnings is marked @NonNull but is null");
    }
  }
```

So, if you use createHandlerResult(credential, new SimplePrincipal(), null), NullPointerException will throw at runtime.It will be catched by  `catch (Exception var15)`  code bock and log the error message you see.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that all the jars are deployed on the Tomcat

I had the same error and in my case, it was that I had deployed cas-server-support-ldap-core-7.0.0-RC8.jar, but no cas-server-support-ldap-7.0.0-RC8.jar